# 4 Primary Partitions for programs, documents, lenovo stuff on Windows. Will I be able to dual-boot Ubuntu OK?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning

On my Lenovo Flex 2-14 (late 2014), I have 5 Primary Partitions, one for Windows 8.1 and one for Lenovo drivers in case I need to perform a reinstall of Windows which has saved me once. The other three is for Downloads, Documents and Programs. I have always wanted to keep my OS clean so that is why I have so many partitions.

The thing that concerns me is that:
With all these partitions, will I be able to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.10 safely? I'm not worried about issues with the OS, I am concerned in case it does stuff to the MBR that renders my computer inoperable?

Comment: If you already have more than 4 primary you're using GPT and not MBR. The limitation isn't applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite a few partitions. Have you considered maybe reducing it down to just two? One for your files, and one for Windows?

But yes, you should be just fine. If you have more than 4 partitions, you are already using GPT and not MBR.

Just make sure to pick the "Something else" option in the ubuntu installer.

Comment: Okay, will do!!

Comment: Just installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my Lenovo and everything is working fine. I know, it is quite a few partitions but at the moment I don't want to mess with anything. Thanks for telling me this!